# Fingerprint.js functionality like for Android

Tags: android, fingerprinting, fingerprintjs2

I've been struggling to find something that could help do the same functionality as what Fingerprint.js does, as when I type something like "Fingerprint", "Fingerprint.js similar in android", I always end up in fingerprint-biometrics technology, but its not what i need. I extensively read a lot of things about determining app installation IDS using UUID as the recommended one to be unique for app installations, I've read alot(out-of-the-box) about java.SecureRandom usages, entrophies, PRNG, things that might help me figure out uniquely identifying an app, but apart from that I need something like what Fingerprint.js does,

**so here is the goal for the functionality the project tries to achieve**

- uniquely identify Anonymous user per app installation on different devices (this can be achieved simply with UUID)
- generate a Fingerprint(not literal fingerprint) that will determine user based on certain behaviors (this is the hardest part)

**my questions are following**

- is there any similar library for android that does exactly the same thing as Fingerprint.js?
- if there is not, should I gather the requirements(the criteria for generating fingerprint id) and write the algorithm from scratch?
- if I'm going to write my own algorithm, would you please guide me where to start? (I think may have used of the UUID,SecureRandom etc..)

this is the link for valve's fingerprintjs
https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

there are properties(entropy) in Fingerprint.js' documentation that i need to consider if it makes sense to use it(or find the equivalent in native android app) as an attribute if I have no choice but to write my own algorithm for this

Edit: I forgot to mention that this needs to be locally done, as I'm currently reviewing Mixingpanel for android that likely generates user id for certain criteria but it seems like cloud dependent